# Site Design Launched!

Tags: discussion, design

Congratulations! As you can see, the new site design just went live. Thanks to everyone for your patience.

Also updated are the newsletter template and chat room based off of the new design.

If you see any CSS/styling bugs, please start a new post and tag it with [design](/questions/tagged/design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug).

Congrats again and thank you for being an awesome community!

Comment: Yay! I can see it now! Now all I need is to get to 10k...

Comment: Note: While I can't speak for the design team, I know I appreciate a single bug per bug report. So I'd encourage everyone to try to keep their bug report posts focused on **a single issue per post.**

Comment: Woo hoo!  My first clue was actually a rep-change notice in the top bar -- I saw the new icon and came to investigate. :-)

Comment: Thank the team for us Kurtis!

Comment: This is a thing of beauty.  Thanks so much for all your work on this!

Comment: It's so beautiful!

Comment: Fabulous, absolutely fabulous

Comment: It's awesome! Now I want a tshirt/notepad/mousepad etc. all with this logo/characters! :-P

Comment: This looks awesome as awesome as awesome can be! Now reading stories here will make my day even better!

Comment: Cool! But it's now harder to hide the fact that I'm surfing non work-related webpages :P

Comment: The site has evolved! I love the new look

Comment: As a long time lurker on this SE, I want to say how awesome this new design looks! Congrats WorldBuilding!

Comment: Wait...did he thank the community for... *patience* ?

Comment: Is there any way that SE could put the logo and some of the artwork up for people to get printed onto merchandise? It could even be one of those custom merchandise websites so that SE gets a cut of every order. Artwork this nice needs to be shared!

Comment: The best site design ever in SE! Now, I'm going to sue Puzzle's site designer ;P

Comment: Just came in here specifically to compliment the site design. I love it! The little planet with the rings, the background image, etc. Hooray!

Comment: Thanks everyone! The community's feedback and ideas were truly instrumental in making it an awesome site. [Remember this...](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/2847/brainstorming-worldbuilding-site-design/2852#2852)

Comment: I could write a big long answer about the design, but let me say this: *Awesome Sauce* ... It looks great! @KurtisBeavers - Great job to you and the team! I hope when the main SE I attune to graduates, it will look as good.

Comment: The design highly reminds me of No Man's Sky.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 thanks!

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - My pleasure! :o)

Comment: Yeah! Up voting because of mob mentality even though I'm on the mobile site and have noticed no change!

Answer (score 7):

Dunno what res other users are working at, but I see more than a little stripe:

[image]

... which is perfectly fine by me. Your mileage might vary on the mobile version.

What I'm not as happy with is the super faint ring on our site icon:

[image: uranian ring]

I want a nice saturn-like-one, which would be more visible than this rather faint, jupiterian one.

Comment: I had the same thought: http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3561/making-small-icon-clearer it looks like they've darkened it in response. Definitely an improvement, do you think it's enough though?

Comment: I see: it doesn't fit itself to the window size, and happens to be a little smaller than the window width on my tablet. It would be so much nicer if the main content just expanded to fill the width.

Answer (score 4):

The upvote and downvote buttons contain triangles that are mathematically centered (top and bottom margins are the same size) — and not visually centered (center of gravity is not in the middle) — within the button. This makes it look off balance to me. But maybe that's just me...

Comment: I can't unsee this now.

Comment: If anyone needs a geometry refresher, the center of gravity (the centroid) of the triangle lies 2/3 of the the way along the triangle's vertical symmetry axis.

Answer (score 3):

For those interested in a behind-the-scenes look at how our design came to be, check out the [interview with Kurtis in Universe Factory](https://medium.com/universe-factory/meeting-the-worldbuilding-designer-b5fde86de92b#.yxul3rwg3).  Includes early sketches.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't like the **brown screen flash** every time a new page loads.

The only purpose of the brown layer is to make a thin stripe on the right, which I don't like either. Why have a contrasting stripe on the right edge, and furthermore take away from the usable width of the page?

[image: brown strip on right]

[image: zoomed out]

Comment: Could you post of picture of what you mean by the thin stripe on the right. I'm not sure I fully understand what you're referring to, and it may be a bug. Thanks.

Comment: I added a cropped screenshop above. The full screen is too large, so I took a vertical section. This shows the full width of the screen, but a small part of the vertical extent.   Ok, added a reduced full-screeen.

Comment: Yeah, that's a bug. Will investigate.

Comment: One more thing, which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome on Android.  This is a Galaxy Tab pro (12 inch).

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I get the brown (or gray, on meta) flash in Chrome on Mac and Firefox on Windows.  It lingers longer on the former, though I don't know if that's due to browser, hardware, or network differences.

Comment: @MonicaCellio it's probably due to loading rendering so gaphics. I'm going to do some work in combining the layers in the header and it should resolve both of the issues mentioned.

Comment: @JDługosz I think we've fixed this. Can you confirm that it looks good now?

Comment: @KurtisBeavers I was seeing the brown flash and it's gone for me, wasn't seeing the other issue so can't comment on that.

Comment: It is ok (but slow) *sometimes*, and shows the all-brown screen *sometimes* for a duration that's longer than the "flash".

Comment: Why there are two volcanoes on the [error page](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/error)? Is it a reference to something?

Comment: @Vi. error = "something blew up", maybe?  The 404 has a black hole.  I haven't seen the captcha page so I don't know what they put there.  But, more broadly, the designers do try to customize the images on those pages, and drawing from the site design makes sense.

Comment: The stripe is gone now for the majority of the page, but still present at the top (i.e. above the white div).

Comment: I still see the brown flash of unstyled content in Firefox on Mac every time I come to a page, even when I use the back button.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers: I'm not sure whether we're talking about the same thing, but, for at least the past 2 or 3 months, and maybe since day 1, I have usually (not always) seen a brown flash when I load or refresh a WB.SE page (in IE 11).  I have just now (2016-09-06) observed it again: after refreshing, I got [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/iFyD8.png) for a couple of seconds before [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vBtNO.png) loaded. It usually doesn't last nearly that long — just enough to be distracting. (I don't understand what the "brown stripe" phenomenon is, so I don't know what to look for.)